# Can you make your own dua instead of duas that are already prescribed?

Tags: dua

The common dua for breaking fast is:

> اللَّهُمَّ لَكَ صُمْتُ وَعَلَى رِزْقِكَ أَفْطَرْتُ
>
> (Abu Dawood)

Can you change this dua? Will it be allowed?

Comment: Dua is simply supplication. Why would you think you can’t make your own?

Comment: I meant for duas which have been prescribed by the Prophet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a hadith in the Book Sahih al Bukhari is the following hadith:

> Narrated Tariq:
>   `Abdullah said, "The best talk is Allah's Book (Qur'an), and the best guidance is the guidance of Muhammad."
>   [Reference](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/125)

So the best duaas are the duaas the Prophet (SAW) taught the Companions(RA) and by inference, us. You can make duaas in addition to the duaas in the Sunnah, whether in Arabic or your own tongue as long as they are not duaas to ask for haraam things or cutting off relations.